# Python/Pygame Trouble with Game loop/Getting code to run

Tags: python, pygame, game-loop

For the past few days I've been working on this code for pong and I've almost got it running. Everything works up to the movement of the objects. The screen just freezes when the pygame window opens. There seems to be something wrong in my main() but I am still fairly new to python/pygame and am lost as to what is wrong.

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()

SCR_WID, SCR_HEI = 640, 480
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = 16, SCR_HEI/2
        self.x1, self.y1 = SCR_WID-16, SCR_HEI/2
        self.speed = 3
        self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 64
        self.score = 0
        self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)

    def scoring(self):
            scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (0,0,0))
            screen.blit(scoreBlit, (32, 16))
            if self.score == 10:
                print ("player 1 wins!")
                exit()

    def scoring1(self):
            scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (0,0,0))
            screen.blit(scoreBlit, (SCR_HEI+92, 16))
            if self.score == 10:
                print ("Player 2 wins!")
                exit()

    def movement(self):
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                self.y -= self.speed
            elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                self.y += self.speed

            if self.y <= 0:
                self.y = 0
            elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-64:
                self.y = SCR_HEI-64

            keys1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys1[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.y1 -= self.speed
            elif keys1[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.y1 += self.speed

            if self.y1 <= 0:
                self.y1 = 0
            elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-64:
                self.y1 = SCR_HEI-64

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (self.x1, self.y1, self.padWid, self.padHei))



class Ball():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x, self.y = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
        self.x1, self.y1 = SCR_WID/2, SCR_HEI/2
        self.speed_x = -3
        self.speed_y = 3
        self.size = 8

    def movement(self):
        self.x += self.speed_x
        self.y += self.speed_y

        if self.y <= 0:
            self.speed_y *= -1
        elif self.y >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
            self.speed_y *= -1

        if self.x <= 0:
            self.__init__()
            enemy.score += 1
        elif self.x >= SCR_WID-self.size:
            self.__init__()
            self.speed_x = 3
            player.score += 1
        for n in range(-self.size, player.padHei):
            if self.y == player.y + n:
                    if self.x <= player.x + player.padWid:
                        self.speed_x *= -1
                        break
            n += 1
        self.x1 += self.speed_x
        self.y1 += self.speed_y

        if self.y1 <= 0:
            self.speed_y *= -1
        elif self.y1 >= SCR_HEI-self.size:
            self.speed_y *= -1

        if self.x1 <= 0:
            self.__init__()
            enemy.score += 1
        elif self.x1 >= SCR_WID-self.size:
            self.__init__()
            self.speed_x = 3
            player.score += 1
        for n in range(-self.size, enemy.padHei):
            if self.y1 == enemy.y1 + n:
                    if self.x1 >= enemy.x1 - enemy.padWid:
                        self.speed_x *= -1
                        break
            n += 1

    def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (112,138,144), (self.x, self.y, 8, 8))

SCR_WID, SCR_HEI = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCR_WID, SCR_HEI))
player = Player() 
ball = Ball()
enemy = Player()


def main():
    running = True
    while running == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print ("Game exited by user")
                exit()
            else:
                running = False
    pygame.font.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    backgroundimage = pygame.image.load("background.png")
    pygame.display.set_caption("Justin's pong")
    ball.movement()
    player.movement()
    enemy.movement()
    position = (0,0)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(backgroundimage, position)
    ball.draw()
    player.draw()
    player.scoring()
    enemy.draw()
    enemy.scoring1()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
running = True
while running == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print ("Game exited by user")
            exit()
        else:
            running = False
```

You are correctly getting the events, but if there aren't any events (as there aren't in the beginning), you will run forever, checking for events.

I assume you want the rest of your code to run in the while loop as well, so you should indent it.

Comment: Wow that seemed to almost completely fix my problem! Now when I run the code, the game runs, but the only way it runs is if my mouse is moving constantly on the pygame window. Kinda odd. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @JustinFarr get rid of the running variable, and make the loop a while True

Comment: Never mind I just fixed my own question. Thanks a lot for your help!